How to insert custom data into QTI v2.2 XML
I'm creating QTI v2.2 XML for a multiple-choice question.
The question contains fields such as prompt, responses, correct answer, description, language, grade (standard), etc.
For prompt, responses, and correct answer, there are predefined tags in QTI v2.2, which I am already using.
However, for description, language, and grade (standard), there are no predefined tags in QTI v2.2.
Should I create custom tags with their names and structure on my own, or is there another way to include this information?

Have you seen following : https://www.1edtech.org/standards/qti/index  What programming language are you using to generate XML.  Have you considered Powershell?

Yes @jdweng, I've gone through https://www.1edtech.org/standards/qti/index this. I'll be using C# to generate the XML. But my main doubt is that is there any predefined way in QTI to insert custom data in the XML which is specific to my webpage?

QTI has schemas so it is best to use tags/attributes from the schema(s).  See Best Practices : https://www.1edtech.org/standards/qti/index
